# When running python module using poll() method (in opensuse) the terminal shows a return value of None?

Tags: python, opensuse, subprocess

I'm creating a hardening tool for popular versions of linux (RHEL,
opensuse, ubuntu, etc.) I'm currently testing my code in an OpenSUSE
environment using the zypper package manager.

I have this snippet of code:

```
message = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/zypper","-n","install","vlock"],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell = False) 
details = message.stdout.readlines()
print message.poll()
```

This will install the package, in this case vlock, and then read in
the output from the shell, and then print the success value which will
either be a 0 or nonzero number.  when I run this code in the python
interpreter I can either print message.poll() or     echo $? if I run
the command outside of the interpreter and I get a 0 for success or a
nonzero for failure as expected.

However when I actually run the full unit-test script from the shell:

```
sudo ./pkghelper.py
```

I print out the message.poll() value which is supposed to hold the
same returned value from the finished process as either printing
message.poll() or echo $? however instead of the value being an
integer of 0 or nonzero, I get a value of None.  Does anyone know why
the value in the python interpreter is an integer and the value when
running the script is None?!?!  this is actually a major hinderance in
the continuation of the development of the program and I can find
anything online

Answer (score 1):

The value is `None` when the process is running and it will be a 0 if it exited without error. Since you are calling it in the interpreter, the process has already finished and exited with a return code of 0. But, when you run it as a script, python keeps going faster than the call finishes(and it doesn't wait on the call), so it gets a None, signifying that the process is still running. The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) docs explain this.